# IntelliJ 10 issue with JUNIT custom runner

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I have custom runner of JUNIT.
The runner run a few tests.
The problem is that the parent object of the test is colored incorrectly.

The correct behavior will be to mark the entire test as red in case of one of the tests are failed, however the intellij 10 mark the test success/fail based on the last test result.

This is work ok with IntelliJ 9.

Comment: Have you tried asking Jetbrains, they have a forum and are usually fairly responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report, the issue has been fixed. You will find a fix in the next IDEA update (10.0.2) when it's available.